# Moment of Inertia of Tetrahedron

Tags: moment-of-inertia

How do you calculate the moment of inertia of a regular tetrahedron of side a about an axis passing through the center of one of the phases and perpendicular to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment of inertia is given by $\frac{m*s^2}{20}$, where $m$ refers to mass and $s$ refers to the length of a side of the tetrahedron.  You can read up on the proof over [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-a-triple-integrals/session-74-triple-integrals-rectangular-and-cylindrical-coordinates/MIT18_02SC_we_74_comb.pdf) and [here](http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/sciencepublications/jmssp/2005/8-11.pdf).

Comment: but how to calculate it?

Comment: What do you mean?  You can just apply the formula by substituting values

Comment: how do we get to the formula?

Comment: Oh ok.  Please wait a while.   The proof is rather complicated, so you could refer to the links attached.

Comment: @user489002 did this help?